# how to write a js function that accepts 2 inputs and loops over zt string and prints the position of the first occurrence of that specified character

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunc(str,x){
  for(i=0; i<str.length; i++){
      if (str.indexOf(x)===i){
          console.log(str.indexOf(x)); 
          break
      }else {
          console.log("character not found")
      }
  }
 }
 myFunc("abcdefg","e");
```

i wanted to write a javascript function that accept a string and a single character as inputs and iterates over that string, and prints the position of the first occurrence of the specified character and If the character is not found to console log the character is not found. 
And the above code i wrote does print the position but still prints out "character not found" for the characters before "e". how can i amend it? thanks

Comment: You already did it ! 
however if do you want to return the value you can use return keyword instead of the break keyword
`return str.indexOf(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move out that `console.log()` from the loop.

An alternative is returning after a letter is found and putting the `console.log` outside from that loop.

```js
function myFunc(str, x) {
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.indexOf(x) === i) {
      console.log(str.indexOf(x));
      return;
    }
  }

  console.log("character not found")
}
myFunc("abcdefg", "e");
myFunc("abcdefg", "h");
```